# Cassandra slow reads with Consistency=ONE

Tags: cassandra

I have a 3-node cluster. 
Setup 1: ReplicationFactor=3, writes with Consistency=QUORUM, reads with Consistency=ONE.
Setup 2: ReplicationFactor=1, reads with Consistency=ONE.

Row and key caches are disabled.
Multithreaded client with connections split equally among cluster nodes.

Reads are about 50% faster with setup 2.
Also with Setup 1 there is great variance in the latencies between the various threads, with some of them taking twice as long as the others. With Setup 2 the latencies of the various threads are more uniform.

Comment: Assuming the question is why is 2 slower sometimes did you have a token aware client? I'm assuming 66% of the time you required 2 network hops (One to the coordinator, then one from the coordinator to the node with the data)

Comment: This is what I suspect too. But since I have a 3-node cluster, ReplicationFactor=3, Consistency=ONE why does the network hop occur? All nodes should have all tokens. I have also disabled the dynamic snitch. I'm using the Apache CQL3 Java client (the one using execute_cql3_query, execute_cql3_statement etc)

Comment: What you've written above is that setup 2 has ReplicationFactor 1.

Comment: Setup 1 (RF=3) has the problem. Setup 2 (RF=1) is fine.

Comment: Also, with Setup 1 (RF=3) if I shut down two of the nodes and just read from the remaining node the throughput stays about the same. I would expect 3 times the throughput when I read from three nodes as opposed to just one.

Comment: What driver are you using?

Comment: I'm using the Apache CQL3 Java driver (the one using execute_cql3_query, execute_preparared_cql3_query)

Comment: Try with the non_blocking calls async and see if the problem persists,

For x in 10000
add to result_array execute_async(query)
for result in result_array
result.get()